# Am new to java. trying to find First recurring character in a string.I don't know where it was wrong.below is my code

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    String s=br.readLine();
    char[] ch=s.toCharArray();
    findtherepeatechar(ch);
}
private static char findtherepeatechar(char[] ch) {
    int i;
    int count[]= {0};
    for( i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {
        count[ch[i]]++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
        if(count[ch[i]]>1) {
            return ch[i];
        }else {
            return '\0';
        }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Enter the string

ABCD

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   65     at strs.findtherepeatechar(strs.java:18)    at
>   strs.main(strs.java:12)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A debugger will tell you pretty quickly.  That count array is clearly not right.  You appear to want a count for each letter, but that's not what you allocated at the start of your method.

Comment: Also take a look to [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
`IndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you are out of your array.

Comment: change int count = {0} to int count[]= new int[1000];

Answer (score 0):

A few small updates (the array being the most important one) should be enough:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    String s = br.readLine();
    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(findtherepeatechar(ch));
}

private static char findtherepeatechar(char[] ch) {
    int i;
    int count[] = new int[256];
    for (i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        count[ch[i]]++;
        if (count[ch[i]] > 1) {
            return ch[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since the ch[i] values range from 0 to 255 (well... not 100% correct) you need the an array of length 256. You also want to add System.out.println in the end of your main method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = reader.readLine();

    if(line!=null) {
        //add every character into the array
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            char x = line.charAt(i);
            chars.add(x);
        }

        //check if some character is duplicate
        firstloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            char c = line.charAt(i);
            for (int j = i+1; j < chars.size(); j++) {
                Character a = chars.get(j);
                if (a == c) {
                    //If character is duplicate
                    //System.out.println("Character: "+ a + " is duplicate.");
                    //TODO
                    break firstloop;
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)?

```
private static void findTheRepeatedChar(char[] characters) {
    /*
     * logic: char are inserted as keys and their count as values. If map
     * contains the char already then increase the value by 1
     */
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (Character character : characters) {
        if (map.containsKey(character)) {
            map.put(character, map.get(character) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(character, 1);
        }
    }
    // Obtaining set of keys
    Set<Character> keys = map.keySet();
    /*
     * Display count of chars if it is greater than 1. All duplicate chars
     * would be having value greater than 1.
     */
    for (Character ch : keys) {
        if (map.get(ch) > 1) {
            System.out.println("Char " + ch + " " + map.get(ch));
        }
    }
}
```

I commented the code to make you understand its logic.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is pretty simple. If we have not seen the character in the string, we put it in the hash table else we will print it

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] dummyList= {"ABCA", "BCABA", "ABC", "DBCABA"};
    for (String s : dummyList) {
        System.out.println("Result=" + findIfStringHasRecurringChar(s));
    }
 }

 private static Character findIfStringHasRecurringChar(String s) {
    Hashtable<Character, Integer> letters = new Hashtable<>();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (!letters.containsKey(c)) 
            letters.put(c, 1);
        else 
            return c;      
    }
    return null;
 }
```

The output is:

```
Result=A
Result=B
Result=null
Result=B
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few problems in your code,

1. First of all, not affecting the compiler but our eyes and your code lisibility, take a look to the [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Use camel case for lisibility, `findTheRepeatedChar` instead of `findtherepeatedchar`

2. Also take a look into [Java arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm)

`int[] count = {0}` will define an array of fixed size 1 so when you will try to access a bigger index it will throw an exception.

So you better define a bigger array (`int bigArray = new int[bigNumber]`) or use another structure like `Lists` or `Maps` depending on your application.